# Laravel. Json column with cast as array are returning as a string when using JOIN in query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

**Laravel 8.**
I have two tables(models) '`employees`' and '`positions`'. In a model '`employees`' I have a casts:

```
protected $casts = [
     'academic_post' => 'array'
];
```

`academic_post` is stored as a JSON. When I`m getting positions, joining them with employees:

```
$employees = DB::table('positions')
    ->select('employees.*', 'positions.*')
    ->where('department_tag', '=', $this->department_tag)
    ->leftJoin('employees', 'positions.email', '=', 'employees.email')
    ->get();
```

**Problem**: as `employees` table is used in **leftJoin**, `$employees[0]->academic_post` gives a string, not being casted as an array.
I know I can make a foreach loop and use `json_decode` for each row to make an array, but why array casting is not working in this kind of query?
If Im using for example: `Employee::find(1);` - Im getting column `academic_post` as `array`, as **expected**.
**I just want it to work stright from a query, not using any kind of loop.**
Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe this is because Laravel $cast only works on the Eloquent model but instead you used the Query Builder approach.

Comment: actually no, I tried to modify query using Eloquent approach, but it didnt change anything.

Comment: You may need to use Eloquent relationship : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can get your json fields using mysql function `JSON_EXTRACT`

assuming your json string is like: `{"name": "John", "age": 30}`

then you can get each field like this:

```
$employees = DB::table('positions')
    ->select('employees.*', 
             'positions.*',
             DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(employees.academic_post, \'$.name\') as name'),
             DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(employees.academic_post, \'$.age\') as age'),
      )
    ->where('department_tag', '=', $this->department_tag)
    ->leftJoin('employees', 'positions.email', '=', 'employees.email')
    ->get();
```